# how to access get set value from class A to class B

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class A and class B

Class A has:

```
public int ID
{
    get;    
    set;
}
```

when running program a value is assigned to ID ex:123 and destroyed when form is closed and set a default value i.e = 0

Ques: how can i save the value in class B before it get destroyed?
so i can have the can access the value in class B and perform validation.

Comment: This question is somewhat vague. Are you asking how to set an object's property to the value of another object's property, or how to persist data across form lifetimes?

Comment: Your question is fairly vague. Can you provide a little more code to show what you mean?

Comment: Very poorly written and most probably he/she is on his/her first assignment :) See his other questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suppose that `Class A` and `Class B` are win-forms and you are opening `A` from `B`. Write in form `A` a method like:

```
public int GetInput(){
   Show();
   return ID;
}
```

Also in `A`'s constructor write following line

```
public A()
{
    Visible=false;
}
```

In form `B` write following to open form `A`:

```
public void OpenA()
{
    var a=new A();
    var i=a.GetInput();
}
```

Now `i` contains value of `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Observable pattern to help you. Use the next chain: main thread(Form if winforms) sends event to A before closing, A sends event to B before destroying

Answer (score 0):

You can suscribe to the OnClosed event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onclosed.aspx

Basically, you class B could do something like:

```
form.OnClosed += (sender, e) => {
    var id = form.ID;
    //Do something with the ID
}
```

Hope it helps.